# Burning files to DVD

Tags: dvd, burning, burner

When I move files to a **DVD window** (It says Drag or Copy files  to write them to disk) I can only do it once.

If I try to "Write to Disk"  The window comes up "Please wait until the estimation of the size is completed. All files need to be Analysed to complete this operation."

This continues with back and forth progress bar for many hours.
Nothing else  is done.

I tried installing

```
sudo apt install brasero
```

As I read the utility is not installed by default, but it says the utility is up to date.

how can I make writing to DVD work?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually use Brasero to burn the DVD? Its a distinct application and not integrated into the file manager.

Answer (score 2):

### k3b is a good tool to burn a CD/DVD

I have had good luck with k3B. It works well for the different ways there are to burn a CD/DVD disk,

- make a data DVD with files, that you are asking for
- burn an iso file to a boot CD/DVD
- create an audio CD or video DVD.

You can install k3b from the repositories. It will bring some program packages, that it needs.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

If there are still difficulties, maybe you have a hardware problem with the DVD drive.